# Get Table (ObjectSet) based on table name (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

My goal is to use entity frameworks (perhaps reflection), to create functions like this:

```
public List<MyRows> getTableByName(string tableName)
{
   ObjectQuery objectQuery = (ObjectQuery)getObjectSet(tableName, m_context); // How do you do this part???
   List<MyRows> rows = new List<MyRows>();
   SortByColumn(objectQuery); // I can do this myself.
   MyWhereClauses(objectQuery); // I can do this myself.
   rows = ConvertToMyRows(objectQuery.ToList()); // I can do this myself.
}
```

The class "MyRows" is invented by me so I can add more properties. The "ConvertToMyRows", "MyWhereClauses", and "getObjectset" are also **made-up functions**.

Is this sort of thing possible in Entity Framework?

How do you do a sort of "getObjectSet" type function based on Template T or string of the table name?

I'm tired of writing Data Access files that have specific functions just to generate a list of items.

SOLVED:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetTable<T>() where T : class
{
 var table = m_entities.CreateObjectSet<T>();
 return table;
}

public string MyData<T>() where T: class { var table = GetTable<T>(); //order here }
```

Comment: I have the same problem now, have you solved it by now?

Comment: @LeiYang Yes I solved it using public string MyData<T>() 
            where T: class
        {
            var table = GetTable<T>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<T> GetTable<T>() where T : class
{
 var table = m_entities.CreateObjectSet<T>();
 return table;
}

public string MyData<T>() where T: class { 

  var table = GetTable<T>(); //order here

 }
```